# Responsive full-screen background image using angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm looking for a full screen background with Angular Material. This is what I have but it does not work.

```html
    <mat-grid-list cols="1" rowHeight="1:1">
        <mat-grid-tile>
          <img src="/assets/img/bg.jpg"  class="bg">
       </mat-grid-tile>
    </mat-grid-list>
```

```css
    .bg {
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-size :cover;
    }
```

Comment: It's already working.what's the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.bg {
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
    
  /* Preserve aspect ratio */
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

You are using `img` tag, no background image. Use this.